# Add image to actionsheet

Tags: swift, alert

How to add screenshot of tableview to first "action" in UIAlertController?
I tried to do it like that

```
let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
let action = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Share routine", comment: ""), style: .default, handler: { _ in
})
action.setValue(image, forKey: "image")
actionSheet.addAction(action)
actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: ""), style: .cancel, handler: nil))
UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I don't see any problems in your code. Are you sure, you take screenshot correctly?

Comment: Please share screenshot...

Comment: Don't. That's hacking. Instead use a custom view/viewcontroller that will mimic a UIAlertController in ActionSheet. `UIAlertController` shouldn't be subclassed/hacked.

Comment: @LoraKucher - just because you _can_ do it that way, doesn't mean you _should_. Apple could change `UIAlertController` and break your code at any time, Rather than just copying some code you found on SO, take time to do it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code, and found some mistakes

First of all, instead of image use

```
image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOrigin)
```

And if you want to place your image to certain position use imageView

Answer (score 1):

```
action.setValue(myImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), forKey: "image")
```

I need add `.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)` <- this for correct image. Thanks all for help